# I'm trying to construct a PHP class using object oriented PHP that pulls from a database and populates page information

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli

Forgive me If I'm doing this wrong, but I'm struggling with a personal project where I want to use object-oriented `PHP` to pull from a database that then populates the page information, but the page comes up blank. The code looks good to me, but I'm fairly new to this part of `PHP` and I really need someone else to take a look at the code.

Here's a little backstory, This is a webcomic currently with two comic title one with a hundred or so supporting pages and the other is around 30. I want to cut it down to two content pages, the content should feed from a database. This way I only have to update the database rather than constantly creating new pages.

The content page has two variables that dictate what information is going to be pulled from the database.

- `$comicTitle` which for this example is "inquisition"
- `$issuePage` will change more frequently, but for this example `issue1_pg30` is what I'm using.

Here's the whole code:

```
<?php

    require_once("class_PageDetails.php");
    $comicTitle = "inquisition"; //There are currently two titles inquisition and era of high magic
    $issuePage = "issue1_pg30"; // will change depending on what Prev or Next link is selected $_GET['page']; 
    $PageInfo = array();

    if (class_exists("PageDetail")) {
        $Page = new PageDetail();
        $Page->setComicTitle($comicTitle);
        $Page->setIssuePage($issuePage);
        $PageInfo= $Page->getPageInformation();
    } else {
        $ErrorMsgs[] = "The PageDetail class is not available!";
        $Page = NULL;
    }

?>
<!doctype html Public "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtl1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $PageInfo['description']?>" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/test/inquisition.php?page=<?php echo $PageInfo['issue_page']?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/test/<?php echo $PageInfo['image_location']?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/test/inquisition.php?page=<?php echo $PageInfo['issue_page']?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php echo $PageInfo['title']?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo $PageInfo['description']?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/test/<?php echo $PageInfo['image_location']?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comicbackground.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="comicfolder/symbol.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="shortcuts.js"></script>
    <script src="heroes.js"></script>
    <link rel="canonical" href="/web/tweet-button">
    <link rel="me" href="https://twitter.com/">
    <title>
        <?php echo $PageInfo['title']?>
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1></h1>
        </header>
        <nav class="main_menu">
            <?php include("../../includes/subs/inc_nav.php"); ?>
        </nav>
        <figure><a href="inquisition.php?page=<?php echo $PageInfo['next_page']?>"><img src="<?php echo $PageInfo['image_location']?>" alt="<?php echo $PageInfo['description']?>"></a>
            <figcaption>
                <h4><time datetime="<?php echo $PageInfo['publish_date']?>"> </time><?php echo $PageInfo['publish_date']?><!-- July 9, 2018 --></h4>
                <p></p>
                <p>By Justin Burke</p>
                <p>A shout out to my newest followers
                </p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <nav id="page_nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../first.php">FIRST</a></li>
                <li><a class="prev" href="inquisition.php?page=<?php echo $PageInfo['previous_page']?>">PREVIOUS</a></li>
                <li><a class="next" href="inquisition.php?page=<?php echo $PageInfo['next_page']?>">NEXT</a></li>
                <li>
                    <?php include("../includes/inc_last.php"); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry I know that was a lot, but I want to give you all as much detail as possible.

Here is the code I created for the class (`class_PageDetails.php`)

```
class PageDetail {
    private $DBConnect = NULL;
    private $comicTitle = "";
    private $issuePage = "";
    function __construct() {
        include("inc_PageDetailsDB.php");
        $this->DBConnect = $DBConnect;
    }
    function __destruct () {
        if(!$this->DBConnect->connect_error)
            $this->DBConnect->close();
    }
    public function setComicTitle ($comicTitle) { //this section sets the comic title so the page knows to display content with title inquisition. If the comic title doesn't match the DB it comes back ""
        if($this->comicTitle != $comicTitle) { 
            $SQLString = "SELECT * FROM page_details " .
                " where comic_title = '" .
                $this->comicTitle . "'";
            $QueryResult = @$this->DBConnect->
                query($SQLString);
            if ($QueryResult === FALSE){
                $this->comicTitle = "";
            }
        }
    }
    public function setIssuePage ($issuePage) { //This section should set the Issue page so it only show the content for a particular page in this case issue1 page 30. If the issue page doesn't match the DB it comes back ""
        if($this->issuePage != $issuePage) {
            $this->issuePage = $issuePage;
            $SQLString = "SELECT * FROM page_details " .
                " where issue_page = '" .
                $this->issuePage. "'";
            $QueryResult = @$this->DBConnect->
                query($SQLString);
            if ($QueryResult === FALSE){
                $this->issuePage = "";
            }
        }
    }
    public function getPageInformation () {
        $retval = FALSE;
        if ($this->comicTitle != "" && $this->issuePage != "") { //this function should gather all content in the db table into an assoc array that is used to display the pages content.
            $SQLString = "SELECT * FROM page_details " .
                " where comic_title = '" .
                $this->comicTitle . "'".
                " AND issue_page = '".
                $this->issuePage . "'";
            $QueryResult = @$this->DBConnect->
                query($SQLString);
            if ($QueryResult != FALSE) {
                $retval = $QueryResult->fetch_assoc();
            }

        }
     return($retval);
    }
}
```

Here's the code for my DBconnect:

```
$ErrorMsgs = array();
$DBConnect = @new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
if ($DBConnect->connect_errno)
    $ErrorMsgs[] = "Unable to connect to the database server." .
        " Error code " . $DBConnect-connect_errno
        . ": " . $DBConnect->connect_error;
```

and here's an image of the DB table

[image: database image]

Like I said the code looks good to me and I based it off the one project I did in school, but when I load the page it comes up blank, which means I messed up somewhere or I'm missing something (not surprising).

when I comment out

```
if (class_exists("PageDetail")) {
    $Page = new PageDetail();
    $Page->setComicTitle($comicTitle);
    $Page->setIssuePage($issuePage);
    $PageDetails = $Page->getPageInformation();
} else {
    $ErrorMsgs[] = "The PageDetail class is not available!";
    $Page = NULL;
}
```

On the content page, the non-class related content displays, telling me that either my code is wrong in the section above or in the class itself. I'm just not sure what I'm missing.

Any advice, support, information letting me know what I'm doing wrong would be great. I know this might be too specific to help other people but I could really use the help.

Comment: The problem with that, when I checked the error log it came up blank, which could be a limitation of my server. I based the code on a project I had in school, and the book used an include file in the class when it introduced them.

Comment: You catch database errors, but only store them away and never output them.
Print the contents of your $ErrorMsgs array (i,e, `print_r($ErrorMsgs);` ) and turn on error_reporting and display_errors while you're developing and before deploying the prject to the public, That will help immensely with debugging.

Comment: I have all errors set to show, but nothing is displaying.

Comment: @Mastacheata I was able to  get error to show  thank you, but being a noob I'm not sure what to do with it. Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /home/ofheroes/public_html/test/inc_PageDetailsDB.php on line 6

Comment: `$DBConnect-connect_errno` ???? Are you sure there are no errors in the log? Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I was able to actually get the error log to work, again Im a noob so thanks for helping figure that out. The page is no longer coming up blank, but the content from the database table isn't populating now.

Comment: The error message tells you where to look. So what is the line 6 of inc_PageDetailsDB.php? Usually that happens if you try to use the mysql object in a quoted string or passing it to something that expects a string.

Comment: @Mastacheata I actually was able to figure that bit out, and I'm no longer receiving that error and I'm no longer receiving any errors( i added 'ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);'. I was able to get the pages static information to populate, but the info from the database isn't showing.

Comment: I tested the dbconnect and was able to obtain the table information on a test separate page, so I know that works. Its just not working when I attempt to call it using the external class. Since I'm not getting an error anymore, I think that means $comicTitle or $issuePage isn't setting like it's supposed to, or there is just something wrong with my getPageInformation function. I've edited the original question to reflect changes I made last night, that I know would have kept the db content from loading, mispellings, capitol letters, and the wrong variable name(at least all the ones I see)

Comment: here's a link to my test page [link](http://ofheroesandlegends.com/test/inquisition.php) , no further error's show

Comment: Okay I Know I am the only one commenting at this point, but it's slowly helping me figure things out. The problem is in my **setComicTitle** function and **setIssuePage** function they're not actually setting the **$comicTitle** or **$issuePage**. Since both variables within the class are empty by default and when my functions fail to populate them, The **getPageInformation()** query is empty. Does anyone have idea as to how I can fix my set functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem, with the page coming up blank was a setting I had with my server that I was able to find using:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT
```

After correcting said problem, I am a little ashamed to admit it but I forgot to give myself full permissions to my server, the page was no longer receiving any errors or coming up blank. The problem was only the non-database information was appearing in the browser nothing I was querying the database for. Eventually I was able to track down the error to either my `setComicTitle`, `setIssuePage` functions, or both of them. After reexamining the two functions I identified a missing piece of code that actually sets the comicTitle.

```
public function setComicTitle($comicTitle) {
    if($this->comicTitle != $comicTitle) { 
        $this->comicTitle = $comicTitle; // it was this line right hear.
        $SQLString = "SELECT comic_title FROM page_details " .
            " where comic_title = '" .
            $this->comicTitle . "'";
        $QueryResult = @$this->DBConnect->
            query($SQLString);
        if ($QueryResult === FALSE){
            $this->comicTitle = " ";
        }
```

The script works now and I am able to pull the page information from the database.

Comment: Like I said this is the answer to my question, the class is now doing what it's supposed to do and pulling page information from a database table. Now on to step two of the project.